# Force document mode=IE8 Standards

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, ie8-compatibility-mode, compatibility-mode

So I am having problems getting IE8 to not default to IE7 document mode, as our intranet is set up.

I am using IE dev tools to set plus a little bit of js to check what the browser is reporting the document mode to be.

I won't be able to change any settings other than what markup I can give. In otherwords I'm not an admin, the only control I have is within the browser.

I have tried:

```xml
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8">
```

But this does not change how the document mode is reported, it still reported as IE7.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hutber/9PNLN/1/)

Comment: In IE9 one of the default settings is "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View", I'd assume the same is the case in IE8 as well. Try turning that off then running it again.

Comment: how would i turn this off from within my markup? :)

Comment: It's a browser setting, so unfortunately you can't. Is it only ever going to be an intranet site?

Comment: Yup, unfortunately. Odd that I can't even get the meta tag to work locally. But ok, if thats the case.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One might think is would be a prerequisite, and I would agree.

But whilst working locally I hadn't declared a doctype:

Make sure you declare one:

```xml
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
      <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8" >
```

Jobs a good'n