# IE11 causes DIV element to repostions at page load and async event

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, internet-explorer-11

When IE11 came out it presented an interesting bug on a website (WebForms .NET 2.0) I've been working with. I've been troubleshooting and searching for a solution for over 2 weeks now with no luck.

This problem is happening only for the website Registration page. Once the user gets to the zip code look up control, the click event which is triggered by clicking "FIND" button positions `<'div id="content-shift">` left, outside of it's main container thus breaking my layout. Strange part in all this is know CSS rules are getting changed which would reposition the `<'div id="content-shift">`.

This problem does not occur in previous IE version or other browsers.

Here's link to the page:
https://buylci.com/SignUpNewUserB.aspx

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your code, it's difficult to suggest a solution. You should edit your question to include relevant code.

You can have Internet Explorer 11 render the page as if it were IE 10 or an older version. See [force document mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940621/force-document-mode-ie8-standards).

Comment: I tried adding this to my header content place holder a couple days ago but for some unknown reason IE's document mode would not change. This worked, however, I had to add place the syntax in the pageLoad method of page code behind file.

Comment: @user1535643 Try placing it within the <head> element on the master page, so you don't have to do it from code behind.

Comment: I tried adding this to my header -content place holder a couple days ago but for some unknown reason IE's document mode would not change. Because of your response, I decided to revisit this workaround but with a different approach. To get this to work in my WebForm ASP.net 2.0 app, I had to add 

<code>Response.AppendHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=10");</code>

syntax inside the pageLoad method of code behind file.

Thanks for the input.

Comment: I didn't mean to submit the first comment.

Comment: I'd prefer not to have the whole website emulate IE10 so I think I'll leave it be.