# Toolbar buttons stacking in tinymce on ie8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, tinymce

I have a problem with a tinymce editor in a Internet Explorer 8 application we build at work here. It works fine in chrome and firefox but those are the browsers developpers use. In IE8, the buttons are all stacked and i have no clue where to start with to fix the problem.

Here is the image: [image]

PS: Please dont tell me to change browser, i can't overrule technical department for 900 users. It's sad that i'm still stuck with supporting IE8, but thats life!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, it was the document mode. I added a meta to force document mode following this QA: [Force document mode=IE8 Standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940621/force-document-mode-ie8-standards)